# Delete document in ElasticSearch using Elastica library

Tags: php, magento, search, elasticsearch, indexing

I have Elastica library and implemented ElasticSearch in my project.
I want to delete document from index.
How to delete documents by ids in elasticsearch using elastica ?
I have tried multiple solution but it still not working! 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

For deleting documents by ids you can use deleteByQuery() function which is a function for index in elastica, so you can use it like this:

```
$matchPhraseQuery = new MatchPhrase("_id", /*id of document you want to delete*/);

$client = new Client(/*your client config*/);

$index = $client->getIndex("/*Your index name*/");
$index->deleteByQuery($matchPhraseQuery);
```